# How to serve html+js in node.js from virtual memory?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

#### Context

I am making an in-browser html/js editor, for this I am using [memory-fs](https://github.com/webpack/memory-fs) (virtual memory) with Webpack and webpack-html-plugin to bundle the files that the user creates in the editor. The files are written to virtual memory in order to avoid I/O operations, which would happen whenever any user compiles their program in the in-browser editor.

#### Problem

Using node.js, how do I serve the resulting html+js-bundle?

I know I can use

```
express.get('/:id', (req,res) =>...)
```

to make dynamic routes which I can map to the correct output. I also know I can use

```
res.send(html-string-from-virtual-memory)
```

to serve the html as string. However, I don't know if this will serve also the bundled javascript which will be included in the html file with a script tag like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="index_bundle.js?a9d6aa105c772d02e0f9"></script>
```

What will happen when the browser gets to this part? Will it make another request that I will have to handle on the server side with another `.get()`? What should it look like? I have no idea.

Node.js is made to serve static files from a `/public` path from disk to handle it easily, so I'm struggling because it doesn't allow me to handle the file-retrieval manually (it just asks for the path and handles the files itself) in order to get the files from the virtual memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when the browser sees the `<script>` tag, it will make a new request for the JavaScript file. In Node, you can make a new `express.get()` listener and send the JavaScript just like you send the HTML.

```
res.send(javascript-string-from-virtual-memory)
```

Comment: I am trying to do this but I have another issue. I am using `router.get('/output/:id, ...)` to serve the html, then I am trying to use `router.get('/output/:id/index_bundle.js?:hash',...)` for the JS, however, the browswer is making the request for the JS at `/output/index_bundle.js?:hash'`. Any idea how to fix it? I need the `:id` to know which file to serve but for some reason the browser is flying on the face of the `:id` parameter